# Can i use ammap api for building android application

Tags: javascript, android, html, ammap

I  am trying to build an application using HTML/JS/jquery mobile that has interactive maps.
I was going through web searching for apis that i can use for creating interactive maps(as i don't want to use google map apis) which is when i came across ammap(ammap.com)

I have installed phonegap and node.js and i also tried following the tutorial given on ammap website.But every time i am running the application (from command prmpt: phonegap run android ) the changes that i made disappears and the Hello World activity displays on my phone.

can anyone help me out with where to start from or give any good tutorial link.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. http://www.meda.org/map/ Maybe it is a tutorial that can help you